# How to start JavaFX 11 application outside IDE?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11, netbeans-10

I downloaded:
    - OpenJDK 11.0.2
    - JavaFX SDK 11.0.2
Both files are extracted to path `C:/Program Files/Java/`

OS: Windows 10
IDE: NetBeans 10.0

Paths:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2  
PATH_TO_FX = C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
```

Inside Path system variable add `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`

In NetBeans I created Java Application project named JFXDev which contains one package com. Inside com package is one main class with following code:

```
package com;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Hello World!");
                }
            });

            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(btn);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

}
```

Properties of projects are modified:
    1) Libraries -> Modulepath added path C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
    2) Libraries -> Classpath added path C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.controls.jar
    3) Run -> VM Options: added --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

When I start application with NetBeans it works perfectly but I was unable to start application from dist folder. I tried following commands in cmd:

1. Command: `java -jar JFXDev.jar`

   - Response: `Error: could not find or load main class com.Main`
2. Command: `java --module-path '%PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules=javafx.comntrols JFXDev`

   - Response: `Error: Could not find or load main class Files/Java/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib`
3. Command: `java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules=javafx.comntrols Main`

   - Response: `Error: Could not find or load main class Files/Java/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib`
4. Command: `java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules=javafx.comntrols com.Main`

   - Response: `Error: Could not find or load main class Files/Java/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib`
5. Command: `java --module-path "C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/" --add-modules=javafx.comntrols com.Main`

   - Response: `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`

Later I added `module-info.java` file:

```
module JFXDev {  
    requires javafx.controls;  
    exports com;  
}
```

But it doesn't make any difference.
What I'm doing wrong, any advice or suggestion?

I tried steps from https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx but I get same error :/

Comment: What if you use `"%PATH_TO_FX%"` (surrounding quotes)? The error messages indicate a problem with spaces in your arguments.

Comment: @Slaw It doesn't work either way.

Comment: Same errors or new errors?

Comment: @Slaw Same error couldn't find Main class. I updated my question with new point number 5, where I tried with full path, and received same response.

Comment: If you have a JAR file with a `Main-Class` entry in the manifest, try `java -p "%PATH_TO_FX%" --add-modules javafx.controls -jar <path-to-jar-file>`. (_Note: `-p` is shorthand for `--module-path`_)

Comment: Or if the JAR is modular, replace `-jar ...` with `-m <module-name>/<main-class-name>` and remove `--add-modules ...`. In this case, make sure your module is on the modulepath as well. (_Note: `-m` is shorthand for `--module`_)

Comment: @Slaw thank you, your answer is right :) Write answer so I could mark it if you want. This is answer: java -p "%PATH_TO_FX%" --add-modules javafx.controls -jar <path-to-jar-file>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## "Actual" Answer

Some of those errors you've provided indicate a problem with spaces in your arguments (e.g. `C:/Program Files/...`). Surround `%PATH_TO_FX%` with quotes: `"%PATH_TO_FX%"`. Then, as you said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652036/how-to-start-javafx-11-application-outside-ide/55653652#comment97994679_55652036), the correct command line for you is:

```
java -p "%PATH_TO_FX%" --add-modules javafx.controls -jar <path-to-jar-file>
```

---

## Rest of Answer

From the information you've provided, it's difficult (for me at least) to tell what exactly the problem is. Instead, I'll give some examples of launching a JavaFX application from the command line, both modular and non-modular.

Let's say you have a project with one class—the main class—named `com.example.Main`. This class extends `Application` and displays a simple window. Let's also say that, when the code is modular, the module looks like:

```
module app {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports com.example to javafx.graphics;
}
```

And your project structure looks like this:

```
\---<project-directory>
    +---out
    |   +---artifacts
    |   |       app-1.0.jar (modular or non-modular)
    |   |
    |   \---classes
    |       |   module-info.class (when modular)
    |       |
    |       \---com
    |           \---example
    |                   Main.class
    |
    \---src
        |   module-info.java (when modular)
        |
        \---com
            \---example
                    Main.java
```

Then your command line will look like one of the following (Windows oriented):

### Non-modular

#### Exploded Directory

```
java -p "%PATH_TO_FX%" --add-modules javafx.controls -cp out\classes com.example.Main
```

#### Jar File

```
java -p "%PATH_TO_FX%" --add-modules javafx.controls -jar out\artifacts\app-1.0.jar
```

*Note: Requires `Main-Class` attribute in the manifest.*

### Modular

#### Exploded Directory

```
java -p "%PATH_TO_FX%;out\classes" -m app/com.example.Main
```

#### Jar File

```
java -p "%PATH_TO_FX%;out\artifacts" -m app/com.example.Main
```

*Or if the Jar was created/updated with `--main-class`*

```
java -p "%PATH_TO_FX%;out\artifacts" -m app
```

---

*Notes:*

- *The above assumes that `<project-directory>` is the working directory.*
- *`-p` is shorthand for `--module-path`*
- *`-m` is shorthand for `--module`*
- *`-cp` is shorthand for `--class-path` or `-classpath`*